# Deploy shiny apps with Python on render.com

Tags: python, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I built a shiny app using python and since I was having currently having problems deploying it to shinyapp.io I decided to look for other solutions.
I found render.com, which is way more easier to use and I tried to deploy my app there but I had a problem: just before the actual deployment it asks you what's the start command, which is defined as follow: "this command runs in the root directory of your app and is responsible for starting its processes. It is typically used to start a webserver for your app. It can access environment variables defined by you in Render".

I tried to use shiny run but it is not the solution as the deployment process was meant to run forever.

Does anyone know what the correct command should be? Thanks for your time

Comment: ```R -e "Sys.setenv(YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE='your_value')" -e "shiny::runApp(host='0.0.0.0', port=YOUR_PORT_NUMBER)"```

Comment: @ekaeo i'm using shiny for python, does it works anyway?  Also what is "YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE"?